# its all about the logic: findall posts & the corresponding threads - on vbulletin

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

vbulletin

## Main Goal

At the end we have all the threads (and discourses) where our demo-user is involved.

(Note: This means that we should keep in mind a nice presentation of the gathered results.)

## Details

For working out **the logic** that **enables us to use this** technique - on all Vbulletin (that run version 3.8xy). we choose a demo-page[which is only a example with an open board - visible to anybody without registration].

There is no interest in gathering these data: the main interest is to find out the logic: getting the full discourses one user of a board (vbulletin) is involved). We have to start from posts, and go to threads... in order to get the full conversations.

For testing purposes we choose a free board - with open access to the structure. So here we want to create a **minimal reproducible example (m r e** (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The URL doesn't matter, just the content of the HTML. i just made the example as small as possible, and still exhibit the problem i am  aiming to solve.

### Starting Point

We take a vbulletin (version 3.8.xy) as an example-board - see the page: https://forums.sagetv.com/forums/
note - no login necessary!

..then choose one single author (user) of this board - just pick one...as an example: just for example:  https://forums.sagetv.com/forums/member.php?u=4793 - (we may pick any other)

look for: show all **statistics:**

```
Total Posts
    Total Posts: 4,406
    Posts Per Day: 0.78
    Find all posts by nyplayer
    Find all threads started by nyplayer
```

and then you get a starting point - with the page of the postings:  "Find all posts by nyplayer" - https://forums.sagetv.com/forums/search.php?searchid=15505533

and now we have a page, that is showing results 1 to 25 of xyz postings

```
"Showing results 1 to 25 of xyz postings"
```

...and now we need to pick all the posts - and besides that: The whole thread, in which the user nyplayer is one poster among others. At the end we get all the threads and discourses (of our example-user) nyplayer is involved.

Notice the **difference**: we are aiming for all the discourse, nplayer (our demo-user) is involved in. We re not aiming to get (only) the threads he started. This little condition makes it a bit more tricky to solve the task - and besides that: i guess we need to find out a good method to store and display the data we gathered. Perhaps csv is a good idea - so that we can work with the results...

The task to get all includes skip from **page to page:** ...while having worked out the first pages where we gathered all the threads where nplayer is involved - we can go ahead to the next page - and to the next... untill we reached the end of the pages where postings of nplayer are displaeyd.

**note:** i have added some images to illustrate the two main tasks to solve. a. gathering all the threads of a certain author -
note: as mentioned above: this is more than only getting the threads he has started. Main-goal: getting the whole (!) threads a certain author is involved. This of course includes to go through all the pages (see the attached images). Thats just all.

*Starting point* could be the overview of postings of any of the user of this example-board... - from there we could gain the general logic...

and best would be - to fetch all the thread.

### Task

so the **job** is:

1. first of all: we need to findall the threads (that contain postings of our certain user); ...and while we  got the threads (discourses) of the first page.. ; then we have
2. to skip to the next page - and the next and the next

**Main goal:** at the end we have all the threads (and discourses) where our demo-user is involved. For working out **the logic** that **enables us to use this** technique - on all Vbulletin (that run version 3.8xy).  As mentioned above:  It is all about the logic: So here we just want to create a minimal reproducible example (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ). The URL doesn't matter, just the content of the HTML. i just made the example as small as possible, and still exhibit the problem i am  aiming to solve.

the coding parts, that i have found so far:

### Steps

1. gathering the postings and the threads(!) where our demo-user is involved

.... threads = soup.find_all('tr', attrs={'class' : 'alt1'})

```
tr 
td class="alt1"
```

[image]

2. **Showing results 1 to 25 of xyz postings**

posted By xyz means: that we ve got an certain amount of (for example) xyz postings (situated in various threads):

```
 td class="vbmenu_control
```

[image]

[image]

finally - the last question is: how to store all the gathered data? Which format should be used..!? thats another question.. But i am pretty sure that here some nice techniques are available...

look forward to hear from you

Comment: Doesn't write rows expect a list? So, you string is getting split?

Comment: hi there QHarr .many thanks. Added more stuff: only two things are needed. getting all posts of a certain user (xyz) while pulling the whole threasd of the forum - from the first to the last - that means - getting all the posts (including the threads) .-while skipping over all the pages that are necessary.  As for the presentation - i guess csv would  be best - youre a expert in those format questions - i look f orward to hear from you .- regards

Comment: @malaga please shorten your question in order for us to be able to help you.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη thx for your comment. i have shorten the question and erased all the clutter. Hopefully the main ideas and thoughts are now better to understand. Many thanks for any and all help...;)

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη  - would love to hear from you again - i guess that you have some good ideas on  that solution - you are a great problem solver... - a hero.. - have a great day... - malaga;-)

Comment: Specifically what is your problem? You have clearly explained what you want to achieve, but not what is stopping you from implementing a solution. I'm also confused why you're asking for suggestions on how to store the gathered data. How will you be using the data after it has been gathered and stored? I really don't think it matters too much what format you use -- json, pickle, SQLite, or even xml (may god have mercy on your soul!).

Comment: Also, what is the forum you want to scrape? Have you considered just emailing the admin and asking if they will send you the threads/posts? It's something that could, I assume, be done easily from the server-side with just a few queries to their database.

Comment: hi @GordonAitchJay many thanks for the quick reply.  Well  you got a full understanding of what is needed. I want to be able to gather data of a Vbulletin (version 3.8.xy ) so we can work out the technique here.  And yes - youre right - the output in json, pickle SQLite or MySQL would be great.  Lock forward to hear from you again . greetnigs

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη i shortened the question in order to be more precise. Thank you for the reminder. Look forward to hear from you. regards

Comment: I do not understand why you are using beautiful soup.  Don't you have access to the data *behind* the front end?  Query that database or file system or whatever.  I would *never* trust beautiful soup results for any robust system.  Beautiful soup is great, but *websites can change*.  You cannot expect front end developers to notify you of all layout changes.

Comment: dear Mike many thanks for the moderation and all your hints. Agreed but - this is a great bs4 project where i am able to learn alot. And after the mining the text-analysis can start - with nlp or some nice python packages. first of the gathering of the logic(cal) data is the first step. Again - thanks for all you do and for all your support!

Comment: @MikeWilliamson  i thank you Very much

Comment: Hi @zero , malaga, you are both welcome.  I do not mean to say anything denigrating to beautiful soup, nor to the work that you are working on.  If this is either a learning experience or a "one off" conversion of a website to useful data, by all means, beautiful soup is great.  You just don't want to use it for anything in a product or long term.  I suspect even the beautiful soup authors would agree.  With APIs, the assumption is that *code* will be ingesting them.  With websites, the assumption is that *eyeballs* will be ingesting them.  Best to match assumptions when possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this gets you started.

Can make some functions that will pull out the thread ids, using the postIds. then iterate through the thread Id pages and parse the data. I'm not really going to spend too much more time on this. You could possibly use the comments in the html as well to pull out some of the sections, but I think this is more or less the thought process you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'}
userId = 4793


def get_user_stats(userId):
    url = 'https://forums.sagetv.com/forums/member.php'
    payload = {'u':f'{userId}'}
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    stats_data = {}
    stats = soup.find('fieldset',{'class':"statistics_group"}).find_all('li')
    for each in stats:
        values = each.text.replace(',','').split(':')
        if len(values) == 2:
            key, value = ''.join(values[0].split()), float(values[1])
            stats_data[key] = value
    return stats_data


def get_searchId(userId):
    url = 'https://forums.sagetv.com/forums/search.php?do=finduser&u=4793'
    payload = {'do':'finduser',
               'u':f'{userId}'}    
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    searchId = soup.find('td',{'class':'vbmenu_control'}, text=re.compile("^Page 1 of")).find_next('a')['href'].split('searchid=')[-1].split('&')[0]
    return searchId

def get_page_threadIds(threadId_list, soup):
    postIds = soup.find_all('table',{'id':re.compile("^post")})
    for each in postIds:
        a_s = each.find_all('a')
        for alpha in a_s:
            if 't=' in alpha['href']:
                threadId = alpha['href'].split('t=')[-1]

        if threadId not in threadId_list:
            threadId_list.append(threadId)
    return threadId_list


def get_all_threadIds(searchId):
    threadId_list = []
    url = 'https://forums.sagetv.com/forums/search.php'
    payload = {'searchid':'%s' %searchId,
               'pp':'200'}

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    total_pages = int(soup.find('td',{'class':'vbmenu_control'}, text=re.compile("^Page 1 of")).text.split('of ')[-1])
    
    threadId_list = get_page_threadIds(threadId_list, soup)
    for page in range(2, total_pages+1):
        payload.update({'page': '%s' %page})
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        threadId_list += get_page_threadIds(threadId_list, soup)
    return list(set(threadId_list))
        
        
        
stats = get_user_stats(userId)
searchId = get_searchId(userId)
threadId_list = get_all_threadIds(searchId)   



rows = []
for threadId in threadId_list:
    url = 'https://forums.sagetv.com/forums/showthread.php'
    payload = {'t':'%s' %threadId,
               'pp':'40',
               'page':'1'}
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    try:
        total_pages = int(soup.find('td',{'class':'vbmenu_control'}, text=re.compile("^Page 1 of")).text.split('of ')[-1])
    except:
        total_pages=1
    
    for page in range(1,total_pages+1):
        payload.update({'page':'%s' %page})
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        discussion = soup.find('td',{'class':'navbar'}).text.strip()
        posts = soup.find_all('table',{'id':re.compile("^post")})
        for post in posts:
            dateStr = post.find('td',{'class':'thead'}).text.split()
            postNo = dateStr[0]
            dateStr = ' '.join(dateStr[1:])
            
            postername = post.find('a',{'class':'bigusername'}).text
            joinDate = post.find('div', text=re.compile("^Join Date:")).text.split('Join Date:')[-1].strip()
            try:
                location = post.find('div', text=re.compile("^Location:")).text.split('Location:')[-1].strip()
            except:
                location = 'N/A'
            postNum = post.find('div', text=re.compile(".*Posts:")).text.split('Posts:')[-1].replace(',','').strip()
            message = post.find('div',{'id':re.compile("^post_message_")}).text.strip()
            
            row = {'date':dateStr,
                   'postNumber':postNo,
                   'poster':postername,
                   'joinDate':joinDate,
                   'location':location,
                   'number of posts':postNum,
                   'thread':discussion,
                   'thread id':threadId,
                   'message':message}
            rows.append(row)
            
        print ('Collected: %s - Page %0s of %s' %(discussion, page,total_pages))


df = pd.DataFrame(rows)


print (stats)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: hi there dear Chitown88 - many thanks for this great approach. Guess that i am able to go ahead from this point and work out the gathering of the threads in which a  certain user is involved. 

This is a great stating point. i guess...

i will have a closer look at the options and will come back later the night - at the moment i have to leave the house _ see you later

Comment: hi there - this is great - you get the threads - in other words you pull out the thread ids, using the postIds. then iterate through the thread Id pages and parse the data.

well that is just awesome - later tonight i will digg deeper in your code - it is just awesome. Many many thanks

Comment: No prob. If I had more time, I’d look into using the comments in the html to parse the data as they seem pretty good at getting each part of the post which would make it a little more robust.