# For loop web scraping a website brings up timeouterror, newconnectionerror and a requests.exceptions.ConnectionError

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, timeoutexception

Apologies, I am a beginning at Python and webscraping.

I am web scraping [wugniu.com](https://wugniu.com) to extract readings for characters that I input. I made a list of 10273 characters to format into the URL and bring up the page with readings, then I used the Requests module to return the source code, then Beautiful Soup to return all the audio ids (as their strings contain the readings for the input characters - I couldn't use the text that comes up in the table as they are svgs). Then I tried to output the characters and their readings to out.txt.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

characters = [
#characters go here
]

output = open("out.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")

tic = time.perf_counter()

for char in characters:
    # Characters from the list are formatted into the url 
    url = "https://wugniu.com/search?char=%s&table=wenzhou" % char

    page = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    for audio_tag in soup.find_all('audio'):
        audio_id = audio_tag.get('id').replace("0-","")
        #output.write(char)
        #output.write("  ")
        #output.write(audio_id)
        #output.write("\n")
        print(i)
        time.sleep(60)

output.close()
toc = time.perf_counter()
duration = int(toc) - int(tic)
print("Took %d seconds" % duration)
```

`out.txt` is the output file I tried to output the results to. I measured the time the process took to measure performance.

However, after 50 or so loops, I get this in the cmd:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                       
 File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\wenzhou-ime\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn           
conn = connection.create_connection(                                                                                 
 File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\wenzhou-ime\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 96, in create_connection                                                                                                                       
raise err                                                                                                             
File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\wenzhou-ime\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 86, in create_connection                                                                                                                           
sock.connect(sa)                                                                                                    
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond                                                                                                                                                   
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                                                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                       
File"C:\Users\[user]\Documents\wenzhou-ime\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen         httplib_response = self._make_request(                                                                                
File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\wenzhou-ime\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request                                                                                                                               
self._validate_conn(conn)                                                                                            
 File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\wenzhou-ime\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn                                                                                                                             
conn.connect()                                                                                                       
File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\wenzhou-ime\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 353, in connect             
conn = self._new_conn()                                                                                                   
File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\wenzhou-ime\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn           
raise NewConnectionError(urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002035D5F9040>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond                                                                                                                                         
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                                                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        
File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\wenzhou-ime\env\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send                 
resp = conn.urlopen(                                                                                                  
File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\wenzhou-ime\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen         
retries = retries.increment(                                                                                          
File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\wenzhou-ime\env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 573, in increment           
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))                                                      urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='wugniu.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?char=%E8%87%B4&table=wenzhou (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002035D5F9040>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                                                                             
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        
File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\wenzhou-ime\test.py", line 3282, in <module>                                               page = requests.get(url, verify=False)                                                                                
File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\wenzhou-ime\env\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get                        
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)                                                                   File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\wenzhou-ime\env\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request                    
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)                                                              File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\wenzhou-ime\env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request              
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)                                                                                 File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\wenzhou-ime\env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send                 
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)                                                                                   File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\wenzhou-ime\env\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send                 
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)                                                                                                                                   
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='wugniu.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?char=%E8%87%B4&table=wenzhou (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002035D5F9040>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))
```

I tried to fix this by adding `time.sleep(60)` but the errors still happened. When I made this script yesterday, I was able to run it with a list of up to 1500 characters with no errors. Could someone please help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's completely normal behavior expected. as that's related to `Chicken-Egg` Issue.

Imagine that you open the `Firefox` browser and then you open `google.com`, And then you close it and repeat the circle!

> That's count as a `DDOS` attack and all modern servers will block your requests and flag your IP as that's really hurting their bandwidth!

The logical and right approach is to use the same [session](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) instead of keep creating multiple sessions. As that's will not be shown under [TCP-Syn Flood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_flood) Flag. Check Legal [tcp-flags](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-flags/).

On the other side, you really need to use [Context-Manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) instead of keep remember your variables.

> Example:

```
output = open("out.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")
output.close()
```

Can be handled via `With` as below:

```
with open('out.txt', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as output:
    # here you can do your operation.
```

> and once you be out the `with` then your file will be closed automatically!

Also, consider using the new `format string` instead of the old

```
url = "https://wugniu.com/search?char=%s&table=wenzhou" % char
```

Can be:

```
"https://wugniu.com/search?char={}&table=wenzhou".format(char)
```

I'll not use a professional code here, I've made it simple for you to can understand the concept.

> Pay attention to how I picked up the desired `element` and how I wrote it to the file. and the difference speed from `lxml` and `html.parser` can be found [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()


def main(url, chars):
    with open('result.txt', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f, requests.Session() as req:
        req.verify = False
        for char in chars:
            print(f"Extracting {char}")
            r = req.get(url.format(char))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
            target = [x['id'][2:] for x in soup.select('audio[id^="0-"]')]
            print(target)
            f.write(f'{char}\n{str(target)}\n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    chars = ['核']
    main('https://wugniu.com/search?char={}&table=wenzhou', chars)
```

Also as to follow the [Python Dry Principle](https://realpython.com/lessons/dry-principle/) You can set `req.verify = False` instead of keep setting `verify = False` on each request.

> Next Step: You should take a look at Threading or AsyncProgrammingg in order to enhance your code operation time as in real-world projects we aren't using a normal for loop (count as really slow) while you can send a bunch of URLs and wait for a response.

Comment: hi again - Many thanks for this scaffolding-approach in coding - and for the help: 
in the terms of a learing theory-approach you, really do great tings:.... since you
1. encourage (all the novices here) to go ahead with little steps; therefore you offer mini-lessions...
2. give us mini-lessons visible here in this thread and also with a walk through examples 
3. starting points for us to make the next steps: do you have any idea to solve this: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66111803/its-all-about-the-logic-findall-posts-the-corresponding-threads-on-vbulleti
it would be amazing!

Comment: by the way - i am a long-term fan of your great work..You have helped me with some cool things like scraper  for a. european volunteers and b, wp-plugins. perhaps you have such an enlighting starting-point for the logic that we can use in the vbulletin (v3.8.xy) see the example in the thread...

have a great day....