# Saving a "for loop" iteration

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

When I run the code below, the for loop saves the first text correctly into a separate file, but the second iteration saves the first AND the second into another separate file, and the third iteration saves the first, second and third into a separate file and so on.... I'd like to save each iteration into a separate file but not adding the previous iterations. I don't have a clue to what I'm missing here. Can anyone help, please?

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd

base_url = 'http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/'

end_url = ['1.htm', '6.htm', '8.htm', '2.htm', '7.htm', 
          '5.htm', '4.htm', '10.htm', '12.htm', '11.htm', '3.htm', '16.htm']

episodes = []

count = 0

   for end_url in end_url:

             url = base_url + end_url

             r = requests.get(url)

             soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

             episodes.append(soup.text)

             file_text = open(f"./{count}.txt", "w")

             file_text.writelines()

             file_text.close()

             count = count + 1

             print(f"saved file for url:{url}")
```

Comment: Could be good to use a different name for loop url as : for a_url in end_url... And also is there something missing in file_text.writelines() ?

Comment: Yes, I was missing some stuffs. You are right! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider the following points!

1. there's no reason at all to use `bs4`! since `response.text` is actually holding the same.
2. You've to use [Same Session](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) *explained on my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66139389/7658985)*
3. You can use iteration with `fstring/format` which will let your code more cleaner and easier to read.
4. `with` context manager is less headache as you don't need to remember to close your file after!

```
import requests

block = [9, 13, 14, 15]


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for page in range(1, 17):
            if page not in block:
                print(f'Extracing Page# {page}')
                r = req.get(url.format(page))
                with open(f'{page}.htm', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(r.text)


main('http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/{}.htm')
```

Comment: Yes, you're right!! No need to use bs4!! Thank you very much, now I'll add your info to my noteboook, it's helped me a lot to better understand the possibilities I have at my disposal!! Thank you again!!

Comment: Of course, your answer has opened my eyes to other smart appoaches!! thank you!!

Comment: @CygnusX-1 this is an old answer but you didn't yet accepted it too

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that your code would save anything to the files at all as you are calling `writelines` with no arguments

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    base_url = 'http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/'
    paths = ['1.htm', '6.htm', '8.htm', '2.htm', '7.htm',
             '5.htm', '4.htm', '10.htm', '12.htm', '11.htm', '3.htm', '16.htm']

    for path in paths:
        url = f'{base_url}{path}'
        filename = path.split('.')[0]
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

        with open(f"./{filename}.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(soup.text)

        print(f"saved file for url:{url}")
```

This is reworked a little.  It wasn't clear why the data was appending to `episodes` so that was left off.

Maybe you were writing the list to the file which would account for dupes.  You were adding the content to each file to a list and writing that growing list each iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, @pcauthorn. I've learned that the writlines method receives a list of string, whereas the write method receives a string. Curiously, it was saving. Anyway, thank you very much again!!

Comment: @AndréAlencar glad you figured it out.  I fixed it to write in this answer as well

Answer (score 0):

You needed to empty your `episodes` for each iteration. Try the following:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd

base_url = 'http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/'

end_url = ['1.htm', '6.htm', '8.htm', '2.htm', '7.htm',
           '5.htm', '4.htm', '10.htm', '12.htm', '11.htm', '3.htm', '16.htm']

count = 0

for end_url in end_url:
    episodes = []
    url = base_url + end_url

    r = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    episodes.append(soup.text)

    file_text = open(f"./{count}.txt", "w")

    file_text.writelines(episodes)

    file_text.close()

    count = count + 1

    print(f"saved file for url:{url}")
```

Comment: Indeed, never thought abou that in the first place!! Totally right!! Thank you very much!!! I appreciate your help a lot!!